# i can't post my data to webservice with php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I want to use the webservice below.

http://www.ttmarkaindirimi.com:8063/DiscountIntegrationPointService

```
$options = array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'trace' => 1,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    );

$client = new SoapClient('http://212.175.9.207:8063/DiscountIntegrationPointService?wsdl',$options);

$validateData = array(
        'Amount'        => 1000,
        'ApplicationId'     => 6,
        'ChannelID'     => 5,
        'CurrencyCode'      => 949,
        'Date'          => '09.04.2013T12:00:00',
        'DiscountCode'      => 'XXX',
        'EmailAddress'      => 'YYY',
        'Password'      => 'ZZZ',
        'RefCode'       => 0,
        'RewardID'      => 1009
        );      




    try {
        $return = $client->DiscountCodeValidation($validateData);
            //$return = $client->__soapCall('DiscountCodeValidation', array('DiscountCodeValidation' => $validateData));

    } catch (SoapFault $exc) {


            pre($exc->getMessage());
            pre($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
            pre($client->__getLastRequest());
            echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";           
    }
```

But there is no request.

How should i send request?

Thank you.

These are the functions, response and request.

```
Array
(
[0] => DiscountCodeValidationResponse DiscountCodeValidation(DiscountCodeValidation $parameters)
[1] => DiscountCodeConfirmedResponse DiscountCodeConfirmed(DiscountCodeConfirmed $parameters)
[2] => DiscountCodeInquiryResponse DiscountCodeInquiry(DiscountCodeInquiry $parameters)
)



stdClass Object
(
    [DiscountCodeValidationResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [DiscountAmount] => 0
        [DiscountRate] => 0
        [ResponseCode] => 1
        [ResponseMessage] => -
    )

)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:DiscountCodeValidation/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

POST /DiscountIntegrationPointService/http HTTP/1.1
Host: 212.175.9.207:8063
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.17
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IDiscountIntegrationPointService/DiscountCodeValidation"
Content-Length: 230

001-
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 537
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 21:50:54 GMT

Comment: Is the webservice running on a shared server? Then it needs to be accessed by name, not IP, so it knows which vhost to send the request to.

Comment: no its on another remote server.

Comment: Doesn't your script catch any response nor exception?
Have you enabled soap for php? Use --enable-soap when compiling from source or install it using `apt-get install php5-soap` (for debian or ubuntu servers) if you cannot find this extension among the list of modules installed for PHP (`php -m | grep soap` to know if soap has been activated)

Comment: my response is stdClass Object
(
    [DiscountCodeValidationResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DiscountAmount] => 0
            [DiscountRate] => 0
            [ResponseCode] => 1
            [ResponseMessage] => -
        )

)

Comment: but request is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:DiscountCodeValidation/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: soap is enabled. I can use another webservices.